# Allowing child element to continue/trigger an event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keydown, preventdefault

I have this code against the **document** object:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Is it possible to put an exception on a child `<textarea>` element for example and allow the keydown to proceed as normal on that child?

Comment: Check what node name the event target has, before you call preventDefault …

Comment: The event.preventDefault() code will have to remain there (document) as is without any checks.  Wondering if there a way to add an event exception against the textarea...

Comment: You mean, you can not change the code as shown, and need to handle this outside of that? Then you could probably add a handler specifically for the textarea elements in the page, and stop the event from bubbling up, `stopPropagation`. (Although that might interfere with other stuff, but to be able to tell whether that might be an issue or not, this is too vague right now.)

Comment: Yes, you got it.  event.stopPropagation() did the trick.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per CBroe's input, the solution was to call stopPropagation() when the element to have an exception calls the keydown event:

```
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
});
```